# Unexpected end of file on line 51 when it's not ending

Tags: php

I have a functions file and when I add a function to it, no matter where, it says that theres an unexpected end of file on line 51.

Here's my code.

```
<?php

function newcat() {

    $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);



    if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {

    echo '<p class="login">Please <a href="login.php">log in</a> to access this page.</p>';

    exit();

  }

  else {

    echo('<p class="login">You are logged in as ' . $_SESSION['username'] . '. <a href="logout.php">Log out</a>.</p>');

  }







  // Connect to the database





  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    // Grab the profile data from the POST

    $catt = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, strip_tags( trim($_POST['catt']))); $desc = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, strip_tags( trim($_POST['desc'])));



    // Update the post data in the database

      if (!empty($catt)) {

      strip_tags($post1);

    $query = "INSERT INTO categories (`name`, `desc`) VALUES ('$catt', '$desc')";

        mysqli_query($dbc, $query);



        // Confirm success with the user

        echo '<p>Your category has been successfully added. Would you like to go back to the <a href="acp.php">Admin Panel</a>?</p>';

        echo $catt;

        mysqli_close($dbc);

        exit();

      }

      else {

        echo '<p class="error">You must enter information into all of the fields.</p>';

      }

  } // End of check for form submission

if(!verify("O")){exit();}

 echo'<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="acp.php?action=vc">

    <fieldset>

      <legend>Create Category:</legend>

        <label type="hidden" for="catt">Category name:</label><br />

        <input type="text" name="catt"><br /><br />             <label type="hidden" for="desc">Description</label><br />               <textarea rows="4"  name="desc" id="desc" cols="100"></textarea>

    </fieldset>

    <input type="submit" value="Save Category" name="submit" />     

  </form>';


    echo '<table class"admin" border=1>';

  echo '<tr><th>Categories</th></tr>';

    $query = "SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY cat_id ASC";

  $data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

  $gender = $row['gender'];

  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {

    echo '<tr>';

  echo '<td>'.$row['name'].'</td></tr>';

  }

          mysqli_close($dbc);



  echo'</table>';

   echo'</div>';
}

function verify($permissionName){

  $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME); 

    $query = "SELECT permissions FROM user WHERE user_id = '" . $_SESSION['user_id'] . "'";

  $data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($data);

  if($row['permissions'] === $permissionName){

    return true;

  } else {

    return false;

  }

}





function group($groupName){

  $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME); 

    $query = "SELECT usergroup FROM user WHERE user_id = '" . $_SESSION['user_id'] . "'";

  $data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($data);

  if($row['usergroup'] === $groupName){

    return true;

  } else {

    return false;

  }

}



function gperms($groupPerm, $user) {

  $query = "SELECT * FROM groups WHERE group_id = $group";

  $data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($data);

$groupname = $row['groupname'];

$users = explode(",", $row['username']);

foreach($users as $k => $member){

  list($username, $rank) = explode(":", $member);

}



    $query = "SELECT usergroup FROM user WHERE user_id = '" . $_SESSION['user_id'] . "'";

  $data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($data);

  if(($row['username'] === $user) && ($rank === $groupPerm)){

    return true;

    } else {

    return false;

    }

    }



?>
```

I need to know what is causing this, because on line 51 it says `mysqli_query($dbc, $query);` and that shouldn't be ending the file.

Also I can have this in a different file, and it works, not in this file though.

Comment: Did you have to post *all* of your code?

Comment: If you indent all of your code properly it would be trivial to spot the missing semi-colon.

Comment: @JohnConde Actually, yes, and there's not a missing semicolon

Comment: copy paste this to an IDE and you'll see it's prefectly indented @JohnConde... Might be even too much with an extra linefeed between every line...

Comment: on line 173 there's a missing variable $group, and on 175 a missing $dbc. If I run this I don't get an unexpected end of file BTW...

Comment: @patrick hmm not sure why you're not getting it

Comment: @patrick That's actually in the file that the function is used in

Comment: Probably 'cause I don't have access to your DB and the code will execute differently for me... line 51 is inside an if(!empty)... when I run the code it's most likely empty, so it never gets to the problem

Comment: @patrick True, I edited my question by the bottom, check it out

Comment: You have a LOT of code inside your `newcat()` function. Are you sure that's what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have problem with encoding. Maybe your server powered by Linux, but you use Windows(or vice versa) and your text editor not take into account the difference in the coding under Linux and Windows.

Comment: I could see that I guess, but I've been writing scripts and having them work up until now.

Comment: If you coding by Windows I would advise you to use Notepad++. In this text editor you can use "Encoding(tab) -> Convert to Unix format"

Comment: Servers are smart enough to deal with this, especially in PHP it makes no difference. Additionally, FTP programs running in ASCII mode (or "auto" usually too) convert newlines for you.

Comment: Perhaps the server is using a accelerator that poorly configured and does not understand the difference newline between Windows and Unix. I met such a case on my practice. I do not insist that this is the case, simply suggested as an option.

Comment: Yes, this was the case. I downloaded it and got what I will post as the answer

Comment: But I can't until after 8 hrs

Answer (score 0):

No syntax errors detected.

This, to me, calls for a shot in the dark: Try uploading the file to the server again.

It's possible that due to a network glitch, your file was only half-uploaded, and this would cause the "unexpected end of file" error.

Comment: I've tried that... Didn't help. It seems to just keep saying that. I could just put it in a different file I guess.

Comment: Try that, yes. Also, if you have shell access, try `cat yourfile.php` and see if the entire file is there.